# Failed to download ubuntu Desktop 12.04 iso

Tags: downloads

I am trying to download Ubuntu Desktop iso from

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?distro=desktop&release=lts&bits=32

Every time it stops the download after 142 MB while it is a 701 MB file.

Tell me what is the problem?

Comment: Have you checked you connectivity?

Comment: Using a download manager may solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

We can't tell what the problem is - there's not enough information, what are you using to download it?

If you keep getting the same issue try using a torrent download instead - that will pickup where it left off if you lose connectivity.

Torrent download links can be found here -

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads

Answer (score 1):

Please try the torrent download for your chosen release instead:

http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent